When can license trump first sale?
Alice produces some copyrighted work and commits it to physical form as The Item (e.g. a printed manuscript). Alice then writes "not licensed for resale" on the Item and gives it to Bob (who is aware of the claimed restriction when he receives the Item). Bob then sells the Item to Clarice, who sells it to David, who gives it to Eunice, who dies, resulting in Fred inheriting the Item.

Which party, if any, has committed a crime or tort?
Which party can Alice compel (or ask a court to compel) to surrender the Item while it is in that party's possession?
Ignoring explicit theft (i.e. assuming that all parties surrender possession of the Item willingly), are there other change-of-possession scenarios which would result in different answers to (1) or (2)?
How does time factor into the above? (For example, does it make a difference if Fred comes into possession of the Item five days after Alice gives it to Bob, vs. if ten years pass in between each change of possession?)
Is there any validity to the conjecture that, while Fred might legally possess the physical Item, he does not have a valid license for the copyrighted material and is therefore not permitted to read the Item?

Note: This is similar, but not identical, to Licencing restriction and first sale doctrine UK re. secondhand book.

No party committed any crime or copyright infringement
There is no crime of breach of contract. Also, since the same item is given away over and over again and neither copies, nor derivatives are made, copyright infringement does not apply.
This is all an issue of contract law
Only Bob can have breached a contract.
Bob was the only person given the work that could have been given it under a specific license contract by Alice telling him not to sell it. Depending on the circumstances, such as giving a manuscript to a publisher, film studio or lector, those terms can be assumed industry standard, but generally there will be a contract. This contract can be verbal ("You may read this, but not sell it" is an exchange of consideration), or written. But remember: Bob is the only one that Alice contracted with, if at all.
All other claims would be barred: Anyone after Bob bought the work from Bob or someone in between and never entered a contract with Alice. Alice's right in the book is exhausted by the "sale" to Bob, and the limit of the (implied/verbal/written) contract only applies to Bob. Sure, he breached it, but only he is doing damage.
Note that the text "not for sale" on the manuscript is not the contract, it is at best a reminder that there is an underlying contract that bans the sale.
Alice can only compel Bob to fix the damage
You ask for specific performance, which is heavily discouraged by courts, discretionary in the first place, and likely won't be given at all. But Bob is liable for the monetary damage his breach of contract caused, such as expected damages. Read more HERE.
Time is not of issue for the sale date unless the license is timed.
Unless the license agreement (NOT the manuscript!) contains an end date or condition, such as "for review till 31.12.2024, return till then", then the license is presumed to not end, and Bob must abide by the license terms till such a point when it is changed. As such, the time since he got the book generally does not play an issue in the act of Bob selling his copy.
Time is of the issue in regards to suing.
If Bob sells his copy in breach of contract and tells Alice, then the statute of limitation starts to run that day. Depending on the jurisdiction, usually somewhere around 1 to 3 years later Alice can not sue Bob anymore. If Bob does not sell Alice, the statute of limitations starts to run the moment Alice knows or should have known that the breach occurred.

Also, since Alice gives it (not sells it) to Bob, has there been an exchange of consideration (which I believe is necessary for a contract)?

What I really mean is "unlawful action". I did say "crime or tort".  BTW, you said "if Bob tells Alice"... what if he doesn't? Does the "clock" start from Bob's action, or from when Alice finds out?

@TripeHound So if I write something in invisible ink on the last page of the manuscript and give it to you, then will you be compelled by whatever I wrote?

@PeterM, a concrete example would be e.g. a movie script (or similar materials) 'for promotional consideration'. Given the intent of distribution, "Bob" probably didn't "pay" for the Item, but I'd say there are good odds that "Bob" did enter into a written agreement... despite which, the Item ended up on eBay (i.e. no "special" contract attached to that sale) after passing through an unknown number of parties.

@Matthew It's your question.  So you can say that Bob did or did not enter into a contract with Alice.  But as written there is no facts stating that Bob either saw or agreed to the conditions.

@PeterM, true, and I deliberately left that ambiguous, to give Answers a chance to respond to either possibility, because that is useful information. That said, you may guess (correctly) that I have a concrete example in mind, but also I don't know whether "Bob" agreed to a contract.

@PeterM, BTW, to reply to your snarky question to TripeHound... I am reasonably sure the law requires that someone knows they are entering into a contract. So, no, something written in invisible ink would not be enforceable unless you could show that the recipient was aware of the terms and agreed to them. But back on topic, see (forthcoming) edit.

@TripeHound "You get to read it... I get that you don't sell it" is an exchange of consideration.

@Matthew The SoL runs on "knows or should have known", assuming Alice is a "reasonable person", aka "ordinary person" or "person on the bus"

Never
The first sale doctrine is an established part of the common law in the USA (and most other common law jurisdictions) that says that when you sell an item, you can no longer control what the owner does with that item, even if you have other interests in it such as copyright. You can’t contract outside the law so Alice’s endorsement on the book is of no legal effect.
Now, if Alice had retained ownership, such as by leasing the book to Bob, then she can impose restrictions, but you state that it was “given” which means Bob owns it and the first-sale doctrine (even in the absence of a sale) applies.
Copyright applies to making copies
The hint is in the name. Anyone can legally possess, read, pass on, or wipe their butt with copyrighted material without infringing  copyright. To infringe, they need to make a copy.
This is fundamentally what the first sale doctrine is about. Alice has a right not to have her copyright infringed, Bob has a right to quiet enjoyment of his book. As long as Bob (or anyone else) does not copy the book, Alice has no legal interest in what happens to that particular physical copy.

To be honest, I have no idea how "Bob" obtained The Item. Let's say, for the sake of argument, it was originally leased, and that subsequent transfers of possession were in violation of the original lease. What effect (if any) does that have on subsequent possessors that are not party to the lease and don't even know it exists?

BTW, if an item is gifted, is that still a "sale" for First Sale purposes?

Your Answer here (which I only found because I was trying to answer the question in my second comment, and it looked irrelevantly interesting) suggests that the answer to the question in my first comment is "none"... at least if Bob had the item under a license agreement but not a lease-as-such (which seems more likely, as the Item has little physical value).
